# Why output signal is not symmetrical? What to do?

Tags: amplifier, common-emitter

I am trying to design a 2-stage amplifiers with first stage C.E with PNP transistor and second C.C with NPN transistor.
The amplifier is supposed to have a gain more that 40.

After designing the problem is my output voltage wave form is not symmetrical.

Anyone has an idea?

[image]
[image]

Comment: That means the biasing is not quite correct.

Comment: @Aaron can u help me fixing it ?

Comment: Start by debugging; find out which stage has the problem, then exploring possible causes why.

Comment: Is C10 really 100uF?  If so, you've got very little AC feedback in that stage, and you're probably looking at distortion caused by the nonlinear E-B voltage/current characteristic.

Comment: A 100uF C10 would also explain why you have nearly 40dB gain.

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis i changed that. no difference

Comment: Changed it to what?  And what's your frequency range of operation?

Comment: As a starting point, you may want to consider running Q7 class-A. This is accomplished by reducing R24.

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis to10nF

Comment: frequency is 100k

Comment: Didn't you forget to draw an interstage coupling capacitor?

Comment: 10nF at 100K is still only about 160 ohms.  You want to go to 100pF or lower so the 4.3K becomes dominant.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the base-emitter junction in the common-emitter amplifier does not have a stable voltage. Hence the gain is variable dependent on where you are on your output wave.

Your quiescent emitter current is around \$1.5\ \mathrm{mA}\$. Hence \$r_\mathrm{e} \approx 16.6\ \mathrm{\Omega}\$. If the output swings by half a volt, the collector current swings by

$$\frac{0.5}{5000} = 0.1\ \mathrm{mA}.$$

The current swings in both directions, hence \$i \in [1.4, 1.6]\ \mathrm{mA}\$. Thus \$r_\mathrm{e} \in [15.6, 17.9]\$. Therefore the gain is in the range \$A \in -[320, 279]\$.

There are various ways to fix this problem: decrease the emitter capacitor so its impedance is larger than the dynamic resistance; increase the biasing current so that the dynamic resistance is smaller; put a resistor in series with the emitter capacitor such that the voltage drop across said resistor is larger than the base-emitter voltage.

Comment: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XFaE.png) I did the thing u said but my waveform is not sinusoidal. @user110971

Comment: Is that a 10 Ohm resistor? It is too small. It needs to be around 10 times larger than the dynamic resistance. Also the waveform has improved significantly, even with a 10 Ohm resistor.

Comment: You cannot use R Load AC Coupled << R Emitter for a large output swing!  Then the emitter gets current starved for R25. The asymmetry is not due to unstable voltage, it is because the Vbe gain variations are too high with Vbe AC

Answer (score 0):

Look at the current in Q7.  What limits its range? For 500mVpk into a 100 Ohm load, you're trying to supply +/- 5mA.  Can that stage do that?

The emitter follower is a class-A stage.

Answer (score 0):

> Why (the) output signal is not symmetrical?

The asymmetry or non-linear gain causes more collector current and negative Vce swing to look asymmetrical and also cause total harmonic distortion, (THD). To reduce this distortion, the Vbe AC input swing needs to be reduced.  This will also reduce the AC gain. One way is by emitter degeneration with a series R added to emitter bypass cap. The better way is to use negative feedback and choose R ratios to allow the feedback to reduce the Vbe variation using some of the forward gains.  It depends on hFE and also your (missing) SPECS for THD, GAIN and MAX SWING, but it is possible to go almost rail to rail using 20~25% of the open-loop gain and reduce the THD by the amount of feedback from 10% to 1% to 0.1%.   It also depends on your (missing) specs for Rin, Rout, Fmin, fmax (-3dB)

> What to do?

I prefer to only use negative feedback for significantly reduced THD. (and non-visible but measurable asymmetry THD ~ %(Vp+-Vp-) / Vpp .

**Design Specs:**

THD=1%, Rin=TBD, Rout=TBD  , V Gain =>20, hFE=250 for large output swing, f_min = TBD, Idc <=1mA @10V

**Results** THD=0.9%, Gain=21, Idc=1mA  **OK**

[image]

You must choose the tradeoffs between gain, THD  and output swing.